# Go plugin - "plugin was built with a different version of package"

Tags: go, plugins, go-build

I have an application that loads plugins on startup (daemon). In a subpackage (daemon/interfaces), I have a few interfaces that plugins for this program should use.

This means that the main program also gets imported by the plugin.

I am using Go modules (for both the main program and the plugin) to fix the versions, and I can see in `go.mod` that it is using the latest version of the main program for the plugin.

I can build them both fine, but when I load the plugin it gives me an error saying

```
 panic: plugin.Open("plugins/my-plugin"): plugin was built with a different version of package daemon/interfaces
```

I am using Go 1.12.7 to build both of the packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this by adding a replace statement to my plugin `go.mod` file

```
module github.com/user/plugin

go 1.12

require (
    github.com/user/daemon v1.1.1
)

replace github.com/user/daemon v1.1.1 => ../local/path/to/daemon/
```

It also helps when you are building the project from outside of the directory where the source code is in by using the full name of the project (`go build github.com/user/project/`)

There is a related Github issue on the Golang repository [that you can find here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31354)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, [the issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31354) is still open. The issue opener presented the workaround, which I was able to use. Please look at the history lines below for details.

```
git clone https://github.com/zimnx/central.git
git clone https://github.com/zimnx/plugins.git
cd central/
go clean -modcache
git checkout v1.0.0
go install -a
cd ../plugins/
rm go.mod 
go mod init github.com/zimnx/plugins
echo '' >> go.mod
echo 'replace github.com/zimnx/central => ../central' >> go.mod
go build -buildmode=plugin -o plugin.so
central plugin.so
```

Works for me. Mistery still... :) [The output](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_iwbDSJZi9Qb21czcW4Cbv7mFldqmN1ZupAovnWu6jc/edit?usp=sharing) has been saved for the most curious.